# Checking value exists, showing error message - before submitting form via jquery

Tags: jquery

Can anyone help with checking if value exists?

I need to check that name, telephone,email and enquiry have a value in the form below before submitting the form when the button is clicked...If there is no value need to display an error message.

This is my form:

```
<form action="#" id="emailForm" method="post">
  <div class="left">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="submitted">
    <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='name'};" onfocus="if(this.value=='name'){this.value=''};" class="inputField" value="name" name="contactname"><br>
    <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='telephone number'};" onfocus="if(this.value=='telephone number'){this.value=''};" class="inputField" value="telephone number" name="telno"><br>
    <input type="text" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='email address'};" onfocus="if(this.value=='email address'){this.value=''};" class="inputField" value="email address" name="email"><br>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <textarea rows="10" cols="10" onblur="if(this.value==''){this.value='enquiry'};" onfocus="if(this.value=='enquiry'){this.value=''};" class="textarea" name="enquiry">enquiry</textarea>
    <br>
    <button class="send"></button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Any help is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#emailForm').submit(function(){
  //check name, you can do the rest... 
  if($(this).find("input[name='contactname']").val() == "" || $(this).find("input[name='contactname']").val() == "name"){
    // show error
    alert('error');
    // don't send the form
    return false;
  }
  // if we get to this point send the form
  return true;
});
```

If you `return false` it will stop the form sending... :)

Its the same as with links... `$('a').click(function(){ return false; });`

Comment: I tried this code, it just seems to refresh the page as though it equals true

Answer (score 0):

[This jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/simpletips) looks like it would make your code easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Although the below will work, you really should be using a jquery validation plugin. Many examples around here on stackoverflow or the web.

```
$('emailForm').submit(function(event) {
   var $inputs = $('input', this);
   var $validInputs = $inputs.filter(function() {
                       return $(this).val().length > 0;
                     });

   if ($inputs.length != $validInputs.length)
   {
       alert('Whoops, there is an error.');
       event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: Will stop the form from submitting i.e. preventing the default action/event.